# EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) CLSBetaController

Tags: ios, google-fabric, twitterkit

I'm getting a crash on app launch from time to time which does not make it to Crashlytics, but I managed to get a .crash report and Symbolicate that against the .dsym. This is what I get:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a3f52a48 0x1a3e27000 + 1227336
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a3c79fa4 0x1a3c74000 + 24484
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a3e481c0 0x1a3e27000 + 135616
3   UIKitCore                       0x1a75d8828 0x1a75c2000 + 92200
4   UIKitCore                       0x1a75d8d8c 0x1a75c2000 + 93580
5   ExampleApp                      0x101632888 +[CLSAlert alertWithTitle:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitle:] + 159
6   ExampleApp                      0x1016383b8 -[CLSBetaController showBetaAlertForUpdate:] + 335
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a3c1e610 0x1a3bc3000 + 374288
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a3c1f184 0x1a3bc3000 + 377220
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1a3c0234c 0x1a3bc3000 + 258892
10  CoreFoundation                  0x1a3ed05e4 0x1a3e27000 + 693732
11  CoreFoundation                  0x1a3ecb5d8 0x1a3e27000 + 673240
12  CoreFoundation                  0x1a3ecaadc 0x1a3e27000 + 670428
13  GraphicsServices                0x1ade54328 0x1ade51000 + 13096
14  UIKitCore                       0x1a7fc5ae0 0x1a75c2000 + 10500832
15  ExampleApp                      0x100f08664 main + 99940 (AppDelegate.swift:24)
16  libdyld.dylib                   0x1a3d54360 0x1a3d53000 + 4960
```

So it seems it is crashing when calling `CLSBetaController showBetaAlertForUpdate` which I have no idea what it is, but after a little browsing it seems its either from Crashlytics or from Twitter.

I do have these dependencies:

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
pod 'TwitterKit', '<3.3.0'
pod 'TwitterCore', '<3.1.0'
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is being caused by any of these, I was wondering if any kinda should has had the same issue :)